# Illustrator Ignoring Region Set by Crop Area Tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Out of the blue, Illustrator CS3 just started ignoring the area defined by the Crop Area Tool.  Going to "Save for Web and Devices" now shows the *entire* artboard, not just the cropped region.  It does this consistently for every file, including new ones that I create.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the "Save for Web & Devices" window there is a tab on the right, "Image Size".  On this tab is a check box "Clip to Artboard" which basically tells Illustrator to ignore the crop area and to instead use the artboard size.  Un-checking this box fixes the problem.

A more complete explanation and [full details here](http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/2008/03/of-document-sizes-and-crop-areas.html)

Comment: This seems to be the answer. T. Stone have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case where you need to trash your AI prefs. The file you need to delete is called "AIPrefs" and under Windows it's in \Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5 Settings\en_US. Don't have OS X up and running on my MacBook to check the location, but it would be under Adobe Illustrator in the Applications folder.

Comment: Tried this but didn't work.